# Merge C# Namespaces and Types

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, merge, namespaces

I have two automatically generated namespaces with the a lot of the same Types defined in both but each name space also has unique types in it as well. ex:

```
namespace a {
    class a1 {...}
    class obj {/* same type as b.obj */}
    class c { /* different type from b.c */}
 ... // hundreds of similar classes
}
namespace b {
    class b1 {...}
    class obj {/* same type as a.obj */}
    class c {/* different type from a.c */}
 ... // hundreds of similar classes
}
```

What I want after the "Merge" is a namespace like:

```
namespace ab { // or any name 
     class a1 {...} // keep unique types
     class b1 {...} // keep unique types
     class obj {...} // get rid of any exact duplicates
     class ac {...} // create unique types
     class bc {...} // create unique types
}
```

1. Is this possible without manually doing it by hand?
2. Is there a something else I can do to achieve the same end goal?

Comment: Will the automatic generation of these classes happen a single time?

Comment: Yes Once and only once

Comment: "two automatically generated namespaces" - generated how?

Comment: I have third party created XSD's that each describe a different overall object but the XSD's define a lot of the same sub types. I use  XSD2Code to generate c# classes each having a separate namespace with the same types defined in both namespaces.

Comment: I suggest T4 for this.

Comment: If the generation of the code only happens once, can't you just do a find/replace in your entire solution or project and change all 'namespace a' occurrences and all 'namespace b' occurrences to 'namespace ab'?

Comment: @Jay Even if I do a manual find/replace I still have to go in and compare the object by eye and confirm that each one is unique or not based off more than just the name. There are Hundreds of types which I would have to do this on.

Comment: @Archangel33 if you want a programattic solution, I think HighCore is right. Honestly for the amount of time it would take you to write code to do that for you programmatically, I'd do a blanket find/replace on the namespaces and try to build it. The compiler will tell you where all the duplicates are. If you have a productivity tool like ReSharper, then that would tell you before compile time that a type has been duplicated within a namespace. I have no idea how you'd merge classes from a and b to give you a new unique class in ab unless you did it manually though. Best of luck anyway.